# pandas returns only one column when reading from csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a .csv file that contains hundreds of rows and exactly 6 columns of data.
However when reading the file in pandas and checking it afterwards, it seems there is only one column? I'm using Python 3.

```
data = pd.read_csv('filenamexy.csv')
data.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 52584 entries, (01.01.14 00;15, 15;15, 15;32, 43;15, 15;33) to 
(31.12.19 23;;;;;, nan, nan, nan, nan)
Data columns (total 1 columns):
Date;DE;FR;NL;BE;CH    41611 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 1.6+ MB
```

What am I missing here, pls?

*edit: first lines of filenamexy.csv:

```
Date;DE;FR;NL;BE;CH
01.01.14 00;15,15;15,15;32,43;15,15;33,27
01.01.14 01;12,96;12,96;32,49;12,96;30,07
01.01.14 02;12,09;12,09;28,43;12,09;23,01
01.01.14 03;11,70;11,70;27,63;11,70;11,04
01.01.14 04;11,66;11,66;25,99;11,66;9,09
01.01.14 05;11,35;11,35;24,47;11,35;11,44
```

Comment: Add a few lines from filenamexy.csv to your question. Always try to make your questions reproducible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use semicolon as your delimiter, when you read the csv:

```
pd.read_csv('filenamexy.csv', delimiter=';')
```

Answer (score 2):

pd.read_csv('filenamexy.csv', sep = ';')

Comment: Also works - so "delimiter" and "sep" are interchangeable?

Comment: so shorter and easier to remember